# Run program as administrator

Tags: windows, eclipse

Using Eclipse and Java I am developing a software requiring administrative privileges. How can I run a java program from inside Eclipse with administrative privileges? Is there a better way than starting the complete Eclipse IDE as administrator? Please note I am on Windows. Thanks!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

Prepend runas to your java runtime settings, I'm not a windows exper, I just took how you would do it on *IX, and asked how to do that on windows, so sorry if it doesn't help.

https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows